# How to pick a laptop suitable for Linux installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop, hardware-rec

Besides Dell I can't find a laptop sold that comes with Linux/Ubuntu installed and Dell is quite expensive comparatively speaking.

What should I take into consideration to pick a laptop that I know won't have any issues with installing Ubuntu? I am not interested in dual boot if that simplifies things.

Comment: Not sire where you are, but aive been shopping for good value laptops, and Dell are consistently among the cheapest on a like-for-like comparison, although you do need to wait for a (frequent) special, or interact with Dell and tell them what you can get elsewhere and try get them to proxe-match.  Ofxourse, I am a bit of a Dell fanboi (service tags FTW) and YMMV.

Comment: @davidgo: Have you compared with greater than 16GB RAM? For 4/8 yes the difference is not significant

Comment: As it happens I have.  Its luck if the draw. I picked up a 16 gig, 500 gig ssd i7 from Dell 15.6" system   weeks ago for significantly less then they wanted for an 8 gig i5  (latest gen CPU in both cases) 13"  this week. Do you know you can negotiate with Dell and pay them off against other manufacturers? (In NZ at least, Lenovo have a good deal on a 16 gig/250 gig 13" system right now).  Also, although not so much in laptops with clip-on cases - I've no qualms opening systems and throwing in aftermarket Kingston/Crucial memory.

Comment: @davidgo: What is `NZ`?

Comment: I've edited your question quite heavily because it was leaning towards product recommendations, which are off-topic. I've tried to make it more focused on shopping tips. If you don't like my changes, feel free to [revert them](https://superuser.com/posts/1585292/revisions) (although that would probably get the question closed soon).

Comment: NZ is the 2 letter country code for  my home - New Zealand. Dont blame you for not knowing - there are running jokes about it being left off maps - but once COVID crisis is over, come visit. Its not called "Godzone" for nothing !

Comment: @gronostaj: Looks fine to me! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is fairly close to a shopping recommendation request.  I hope it does not get closed.

In addition to doing research on specific models, a good guide is to look at the chipset components in the board. If the chipsets are common and not cutting edge, there is a very good chance the system will work with Linux.  If it works with Linux, it is very likely to work with Ubuntu - but again, if the chipsets are not as common may require some hacking.

Certainly not a recommendation, but most systems which are full 64 bit (ie not some older Atoms)  and which run a pure Intel chipsets (ie internal graphics) should work out the box.  Although usable under Ubuntu, avoid Realtek NICs as they are crap and a lot of hassle with driver conflicts.

There are brands other then Dell which offer some Linux systems  (mainly Lenovo).  Have a look at https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop - although just because its not on that list does not mean you will have problems with it.  I've run Ubuntu on plenty of devices not on that list. In reality, if its mainstream and not bleeding edge or highly specialist it should work fine)

Comment: So any Intel 64 bit composition should work fine with linux?

Comment: I didn't quite say that. You have an extremely high likelihood of it working if its an Intel CPU with Intel graphics and Intel WIFI+Ethernet. (Thus is not to say its the only combo - but I have, for example, had gotchas with an Atheros 6k based wifi although certainly most Btoadcom and Atheros stuff is OK. Intel stuff seems to be ubiquitous and have good Linux drivers though.). Do you have a specific system in mind?

Comment: No specific system. Originally my understanding was that I can install linux anywhere and it would just work. But I realized it is not like that.

Comment: `extremely high likelihood of it working` what would be an example of not working? Some specific usage or the whole laptop would not function properly at all?

Comment: I wasn't aware about the issue with Realtek and is funny since from your link https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201812-26717

Comment: Your question is a but unfairly broad. Going back to a pretty bad edge case (I knew what I was getting in to) I got me a Dell Venue11 which booted fine, but touch screen did only worked on some versions of Ubuntu and the WIFI card never worked. I ripped it out and replaced it with an Intel one and never looked back. Everything works a treat. I do note that theDdell Venue 11 was never mainstream.  **In the vast majority of cases most stuff will work - but might require.some boot options to work which can require some Googling and some general Linux knowledge**

Comment: Re your Relatek link - notice how next to many of the components there are 2 sets of 4 numbers? These represent Linux identifiers for very specific versions of chipsets which have been tested.  This is because not all versions will be recognised. This is especially true with Realtek drivers, which are frequently misidentified and kinda sorta work until they jam up because of bad drivers.  Please trust me - avoid Realtek if you value network performance and stability. (I certainly did not want to imply Linux does not work with Realtek - just that it is the most common gotcha I've run into)

Comment: I trust you. I was just trying to show that in that certification link you have shared (very helpful btw) I find Realtek every model I check (Dell/Lenovo). So I am not really sure how I can avoid it if that ubuntu certifications is the safest path to pick something